# Error: base class undefined in deriving class Son from baseclass Father

Tags: c++, inheritance, header-files

I made two classes Father and Son, split into .h and .cpp. Why do I get the above Error? I have another Solution with basicly the same includes and no error. Sorry if this is trivial but I'm new to c++ and  confused why it works in one Solution but not the other.

Edit: When I run the program, the Terminal still opens and shows the cout lines of the Father, the error seems to happen after that. I know about the soution with including the Father.h inside Son.h. but why doesn't it work the way I wrote it? I like the Idea of including header files inside the cpp files.

Father.h

```
#pragma once
class Father
{
public:
    Father();
    ~Father();
};
```

Father.cpp:

```
#include "Father.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Father::Father()
{
    cout << "I am the father constructor" << endl;
}

Father::~Father()
{
    cout << "I am the father deconstructor" << endl;
}
```

Son.h:

```
#pragma once
class Son : public Father
{
public:
    void Talk();
};
```

Son.cpp:

```
#include "Father.h"
#include "Son.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Son::Talk()
{
    cout << "I'am the son" << endl;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Son.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Son Bernd;
}
```

Comment: Add `#include "Father.h"` in `Son.h`.

Comment: Yeah I know that works, but why doesn't it work the way I wrote it?

Comment: Without `#include "Father.h"` the class `Father` is not defined when used as the base class of `Son`; the compiler doesn't know what it is.

Comment: Doesn't the `#include "Father.h"` inside `Son.cpp` do that? Or am I missing something

Comment: Consider `Main.cpp`, which has `#include "Son.h"` but `Father.h` is not included, then compiling fails. So you have to add `#include "Father.h"` in every cpp files. It would be better to add it in `Son.h`.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense the way you put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why doesn't it work the way I wrote it?

`Son.cpp` compiles fine, because it includes the declaration of `Father` from `Father.h` before the declaration of `Son` from `Son.h`.

The problem occurs in `Main.cpp`. Here you only include the declaration of `Son` from `Son.h`. The class `Father` is not known to this compilation unit.

Make sure, that each header includes all of it's dependencies and add

```
#include "Father.h"
```

to `Son.h`.